# Running "<" command between two different directories

Tags: shell, command

I'm working a small JS project and trying to get a script to run, which compiles some source files that are written in our own "language x".

To run the compiler normally you would use the command `./a.out < source.x` And it would print out success or compilation errors etc.

In the case now, I'm trying to working between two directories and using this command:

`sudo ~/Documents/server/xCompiler/./a.out < ~/Documents/server/xPrograms/source.x`

But this produces no output into the terminal at all and doesn't affect the output files. Is there somthing I'm doing wrong with the use of `<`? I'm planning to use it in `child_process.exec` within a node server later.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm a bit stumped.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't tell about what is `a.out` doing, nor do you say which shell you are using. It's impossible to answer this question. It's like you were asking "I cooked today a meal according to the secret recipe of my grandmother, but it didn't taste the same like when she's cooking it. What did I do wrong?"

Comment: `sudo`? Why would you run your compiler as root? This means it doesn't get invoked with the same environment variables as commands you run under your own account.

Comment: BTW, there are two likely causes of problems, and neither of them have to do with passing a fully-qualified path to the `<` redirection operator. (1) is that your compiler expects to find supporting files relative to the current working directory, but the cwd is no longer the directory where the compiler itself is located. (2) is that `sudo` is running your compiler in a different environment where none of its environment variables are present.

Comment: @J.Chomel, btw, to answer the question implicit in your now-deleted edit ("why would someone name a compiler `a.out`?") -- `a.out` is the default name for executables compiled by gcc. So, if someone compiled their compiler and didn't give it an explicit name, it gets the name `a.out`, and there you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirection operators (`<`, `>`, and others like them) describe operations to be performed *by the shell* before your command is run at all. Because these operations are performed by the shell itself, it's extremely unlikely that they would be broken in a way specific to an individual command: When they're performed, the command hasn't started yet.

There are, however, some more pertinent ways your first and second commands differ:

- The second (non-working) one uses a fully-qualified path **to the compiler itself**. That means that the directory that the compiler is found in and the current working directory where the compiler is running can differ. If the compiler looks for files in or in locations relative to its current working directory, this can cause a failure.
- The second uses `sudo` to escalate privileges to run the compiler. This means you're running as a different user, with most environment variables cleared or modified (unless explicitly whitelisted in `/etc/sudoers`) during the switch -- and has widespread potential to break things depending on details of your compiler's expectations about its runtime environment beyond what we can reasonably be expected to diagnose here.

That first one, at least, is amenable to a solution. In shell:

```
xCompile() {
  (cd ~/Documents/server/xCompiler && exec ./a.out "$@")
}

xCompile < ~/Documents/server/xPrograms/source.x
```

Using `exec` is a performance optimization: It balances the cost of creating a new subshell (with the parenthesis) by consuming that subshell to launch the compiler rather than launching it as a subprocess.

Calling the node `child_process.exec()`, you can simply pass the desired runtime directory in the `cwd` argument, so no shell function is necessary.

Comment: Oh thanks! I think it was actually both of these issues. The compiler was looking for files in the cwd and I didn't realise sudo worked in that way. This makes a lot more sense now, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: `sudo` has to clear environment variables for security reasons -- otherwise, something like `LD_PRELOAD` or an exported shell variable could change behavior of post-escalation code, making a command that was whitelisted in `/etc/sudoers` as safe suddenly less so.